# what is the difference between calling a function as fun() and fun?

Tags: c, function

I came across a piece of code which is as below

`qsort(array, 10, sizeof(int), sort);`

Here sort is again a function. But I was always under the impression that any function which is called should have `()` after the function name or was I missing something.

I just wanted to know how will this work and what are the differences in calling functions like these. Thanks!

Comment: I believe it's being used as a pointer to a function: http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html

Comment: in qsort you're not calling the function but passing the address of the "sort" function so qsort can call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
qsort(array, 10, sizeof(int), sort);
```

this passes a pointer to the function "sort" so that the function "qsort" can call this function.

Comment: Indeed, and `sort` there is actually the short form of `&sort` - the compiler sees that you're not calling the function, so the only other thing that makes sense is that you are trying to pass its address.

Answer (score 2):

That function is not called it is passed as a function pointer. [see Function Pointers in C and C++](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a pointer to the function `sort` to function `qsort`, so that `qsort` can use the function as comparison function.

The correct syntax should include a `&` before `sort` (since `sort` is a function, not a pointer, so we need to reference it), but the compiler "adds" it for you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the C grammar (e.g. in the C Standard) you find that there is an operator written as `()`, which is the **function call operator**. It is similar to the **array subscript operator** `[]` in that it is applied to an identifier, in this case, the name of the function. If the identifier for a function is not followed by the function call operator, the identifier represents a *pointer* to that function. So now it becomes clear, what `qsort`'s last arg is: a pointer to the comparison function. Whenever it needs to compare two elements it calls the function pointed to by its last arg.

The `sort` function in your example is termed a **callback** function, `qsort` calls it back (several times, with different arguments).